# Webpages coming broken, not loading properly in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, websites

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for 5 months now and very recently I am facing a peculiar problem. Web pages are loading but its broken. Example:

[image: Broken]

Now What I need to do to fix the problem?

I have already tried:

1. Clearing history, cookie and cache
2. Same problem in Chrome
3. No such problem in windows. So the problem is in Ubuntu specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing DNS. I switched to Google DNS.

Answer (score 0):

When was the last time you did an update?  Try a system update from Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You could also try re-installing Firefox.

Comment: My system is up-to-date and I update regularly. And I have tried re-installing Google chrome and the problem prevails.